# upgrade OWA (03 to 07) without upgrading Exchange (03)

Tags: exchange-2003, internet-explorer, firefox, outlook-web-app

*Sorry for the potentially ridiculous question.*

Is there some sort of hack or work-around to upgrade OWA to 2007 while using Exchange 2003? If not, are there any ways to improve the default layout / skin? Maybe Greasemonkey scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

You would probably be better served asking over at StackOverflow as far as reskinning OWA as it really is an asp programming question, not a Server admin question.